# Pass NULL to SSRS URL access parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

How does one specify a NULL value when passing a parameter to an SSRS report using URL access?

i.e. when using the form

```
http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?Report&Parameter=value
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the syntax

```
Parameter:IsNull=True
```

In the example given above:

```
http://server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?Report&Parameter:IsNull=True
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391(loband).aspx