# Passing parameter to SSRS in URL

Tags: reporting-services, parameter-passing

I have a report which is deployed on a server. What I'm trying to do is, pass a parameter to this report so that this report loads as soon as the parameter is passed to report, instead of hitting `View Report`.

The problem is the parameter sent in the `url` is not being set to the field in the report. I have googled up enough to crazy and I still don't know what I'm missing. I'm relatively new to `SSRS` so please assume that I could have forgotten to do something really basic.

This is the URL I'm using to call the report:

`<server Name>/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f<folder>%2f<report>&<parameter>=<value>`

The value being passed is `int` and the parameter name is the same as the one in the report.

All help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't set the parameter using the Report manager URL, now I am not sure if "Reports" is your report manager URL since it can be changed, but it is the default so I'm guessing it is, instead reference the reportserver URL try this:

`<servername>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2f<folder>%2<report>&rs:Command=Render&<parameter>=<value>`

Comment: If you to the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, on the machine running SSRS. Look at the 'Web Service URL screen, that will give you the report server URL.  This answer gives a good example of the URL (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1433488/77198) syntax and a web reference for more details

Comment: When you say `ReportServer`, is it common for everything or can the name be changed?

Comment: ReportServer is the default path, but it can be changed, if you have access to the machine that runs reporting services you can change the URL using Reporting Services Configuration Manager (as mentioned in BobF's comment)